# JavaScript and PHP in code - whats the difference?

Tags: php, javascript

I have this code in my JavaScript part:

```
var opConfig = new Product.Options(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig(); ?>);
```

The PHP call returns me some string, to make it easy, lets say the string is *abcd*. So this code results in:

```
var opConfig = new Product.Options(abcd);
```

Now, some lines later, I have this code:

```
this.opConfig = new Product.Options(opconfig);
```

The `opconfig` variable has the same string `abcd`, but the results are different, `this.opConfig` does not look like it looked before. So is there a difference in how I use the string as param? Something I am missing? For me, it should always be the same call, namely:

```
new Product.Options(abcd)
```

Ideas?

**Addition:** The full call in the JS code looks like that:

```
var opConfig = new Product.Options({"16":{"26":{"price":5,"oldPrice":5,"priceValue":"5.0000","type":"fixed","excludeTax":5,"includeTax":5},"28":{"price":8,"oldPrice":8,"priceValue":"8.0000","type":"fixed","excludeTax":8,"includeTax":8},"27":{"price":10,"oldPrice":10,"priceValue":"10.0000","type":"fixed","excludeTax":10,"includeTax":10}},"14":{"price":0,"oldPrice":0,"priceValue":"0.0000","type":"fixed","excludeTax":0,"includeTax":0},"15":{"price":0,"oldPrice":0,"priceValue":"0.0000","type":"fixed","excludeTax":0,"includeTax":0}});
```

The param reaches the called function as object, no idea why. Calling it the other way, the same string seems to reach it as string. Can anybody help?

Comment: Should not string be used in `'` or `"`?

Comment: `abcd` is not a string. `"abcd"` would be.

Answer (score 2):

Change to:

```
var opConfig = new Product.Options('<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig(); ?>');
```

`opconfig` is a string variable, so its fine passing that as a parameter.

Whereas your PHP code will render:

```
var opConfig = new Product.Options(abcd);
```

`abcd` is not a string variable. Therefore you need to put this in speech marks so that it becomes a string object. Your output would now be:

```
var opConfig = new Product.Options('abcd');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `new Product.Options(abcd)` then `abcd` is a variable name, not a string. You need to add quotes so that it ends up as `new Product.Options('abcd')`:

```
var opConfig = new Product.Options('<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig(); ?>');
// OR
var opConfig = new Product.Options("<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig(); ?>");
```

Either way you need to be sure your PHP output escapes any characters that might "break" the string literal, e.g., single-quotes (in the first one) or double-quotes (in the second one), or newlines (in either).

Answer (score 0):

I can see you're missing quotes:

```
var opConfig = new Product.Options('<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig(); ?>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the below line

```
var opConfig = new Product.Options(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig(); ?>);
```

to

```
var opConfig = new Product.Options('<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig(); ?>');
```